# Bound on sum of $n$th super-diagonal entries in a $2n$ by $2n$ PSD matrix

Tags: matrices, inequalities, operator-theory, convex-analysis, traces

Let $A,B,C\in\mathbb{R}^{n\times n}$ be such that
$\left(\begin{array}{} A & B \\ B^T & C \end{array}\right)\succeq 0$. I would like to prove that
$$\mathrm{trace}\,B \le \sum_{i=1}^n \sqrt{\lambda_i(A)\lambda_i(C)},$$
where for any symmetric $M\in\mathbb{R}^{n \times n}$, $\lambda_1(M) \le \lambda_2(M) \le \cdots \le \lambda_n(M)$ denote the sorted eigenvalues of $M$.

Using SVD, Schur complement and Von-Neumann's trace inequality I am able to show that the above by is true if
$$\mathrm{trace}\,\left(\left[\Sigma G^2 \Sigma\right]^{1/2} G^{-1}\right)
\ge \mathrm{trace}\,\Sigma$$
for every $G\succ 0$ and diagonal $\Sigma \succeq 0$; according to simulations random matrices seem to satisfy this. This inequality follows from a simple symmetry argument if $f(G) = \mathrm{trace}\,\left(\left[\Sigma G^2 \Sigma\right]^{1/2} G^{-1}\right)$ happens to be operator-convex, but I have so far not been able to prove this.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If $\left(\begin{array}{} A & B \\ B^T & C \end{array}\right)\succeq 0$ then there exists a contraction $K$ (i.e. $\lambda_n(K)=\|K\| \leq 1$) such that $B = A^{1/2} K C^{1/2}$ (e.g. see Theorem IX.5.9 of Bhatia's book: Matrix Analysis). By [Von-Neumann's trace inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trace_inequalities#Von_Neumann's_trace_inequality), we have
$\newcommand{tr}{\mathrm{tr}}$
$$
\tr(B) = \tr(A^{1/2} K C^{1/2}) \leq\sum_{i=1}^n \lambda_i(K)\lambda_i(C^{1/2}A^{1/2} ) 
\leq \sum_{i=1}^n \lambda_i(C^{1/2}A^{1/2} ) .$$

By the weak majorization property of the singular values of the product of matrices (e.g. see Theorem 3 of [this paper](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC1063207/pdf/pnas01556-0014.pdf) of Horn), we have

$$
\sum_{i=1}^n \lambda_i(C^{1/2}A^{1/2} ) 
 \leq \sum_{i=1}^n \lambda_i(A^{1/2})\lambda_i(C^{1/2}).
$$

Now, the result at hand.

Note that here $\lambda_i(\cdot)$ stands for the singular values, which is equal to the eigenvalues for positive semidefinite matrices.

Comment: How do you justify the second inequality ?

Comment: Von Neumann's trace Inequality is in terms of singular values, not eigenvalues. Since $C^{1/2}A^{1/2}$ is not symmetric in general, its singular values do not equal its eigenvalues (they tend to be larger). Your second inequality is therefore false.

Comment: @DenisSerre: I think I fixed it.

Answer (score 1):

A slightly more precise result is noted below. You may like it given that you tried Schur complements, and convexity arguments.

> **Observation.**
>   $\DeclareMathOperator{tr}{tr}$
>   \begin{equation*}
> \max\{|\tr B| : A \succeq BC^{-1}B^T\} \le \min_{X \succ 0}\sqrt{\tr(AX)\tr(CX^{-1})}.
> \end{equation*}

From this inequality one sees that the maximum is attained when $B=(AC)^{1/2}$, and equals the value of the min on the right, yielding the value $\tr[(A^{1/2}CA^{1/2})^{1/2}]$.

As a corollary, we also obtain (which is the first set of inequalities in Mahdi's answer):
\begin{equation*}
|\tr B| \le \tr[(A^{1/2}CA^{1/2})^{1/2}] = \sum_i\lambda_i^{1/2}(A^{1/2}CA^{1/2})=
\sum_i\lambda_i^{1/2}(AC),
\end{equation*}
where $\lambda_i(\cdot)$ denotes eigenvalues.